# Looking for a paper on transfinite diameter by David Cantor

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, paper-request, diophantine-geometry

I have been reading about transfinite diameter and its applications to number theory and have been hunting for the following paper for quite a while:

Cantor D.: On an extension of the definition of transfinite diameter and some
applications, J. reine Angew. Math., vol. 316 (1980), pp. 160-207.

Unfortunately, I am an undergraduate and have no access to MathSciNet or other resources which provide papers for free. The only links I got results from are ones accepting a payment which is completely outside my financial capacity. From some advice I got in a previous similar reference-request post, I tried an interlibrary loan but due to the pandemic and no nearby libraries, that hasn't been successful so far. I would really appreciate a link to the full text of the above reference. Thank you.

Comment: To anyone thinking of closing this question, please remember that not everyone has access to institutional support which makes literature access easy. I strongly feel that people who are eager to do research but lack such support should be helped and encouraged. Good answers like Benjamin Dickman's could be really helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your support.

Comment: There is a website called Sci Hub where you can get pretty much any article immediately as long as you know the DOI (which can usually be found very easily), however Sci Hub is possibly illegal so I definitely do not recommend that you use it to gain easy, no-hassle access to any paper which you need to read whenever you want.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hopefully this works:

[Cantor D.: On an extension of the definition of transfinite diameter and some applications](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN243919689_0316?tify=%7B%22pages%22:%5B164,165%5D,%22panX%22:0.966,%22panY%22:0.416,%22view%22:%22scan%22,%22zoom%22:0.464%7D)

---

Since you said that you had "been hunting for the following paper for quite a while," here are the specific steps that I took to find this paper. Probably this will make it seem simple in retrospect, but I don't want to give off the impression that this required a complex knowledge of databases.

1. I googled [the title of the paper](https://www.google.com/search?q=On+an+extension+of+the+definition+of+transfinite+diameter+and+some+applications)
2. I clicked the link to [EUDML](https://eudml.org/doc/152247) (with which I wasn't previously familiar)
3. The sidebar says **In Other Databases** and I didn't find ZBMath helpful, so I used [GDZ](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN243919689_0316?tify=%7B%22view%22:%22info%22,%22pages%22:%5B164%5D%7D)
4. I've never heard of GDZ before, but I saw the paper listed on p. 160 of that document and, indeed, the paper was there

For future reference, there is also an often used website called **sci-hub [dot] tw** that can pull papers for which you have the DOI. You can read more about [Sci-Hub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sci-Hub) on wikipedia and decide whether that is a route that you are willing to take when searching out future materials.

Comment: The link works for me, thank you so much.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the tip! I tried EuDML too, I kept on getting an "unsafe" message from my browser. It could be that the site is safe (could you confirm this please?) and it is some additional layer of security that is not necessary here (however I didn't have the courage to click since I had lost data before ignoring an "unsafe" message for a previous site). I didn't find this paper on zbMath either, but thank you for the information on GDZ and sci-hub, I'll be sure to check them out.

Comment: @asrxiiviii I, too, got the unsafe message; I chose to bypass it manually but do not make that suggestion, in general. A question around whether an individual website is safe is probably better directed elsewhere (definitely not on topic at MO). I can confirm that I used the site but cannot confirm that it was, is, or will be secure.